# Problema con almacenando datos en un array perteneciente a un prototipo

Tags: javascript, array, herencia, push, prototipos

Con este código puedo crear objetos Factura y añadir productos. El problema es que al crear por ejemplo factura1 y factura2 y añadirle productos a cada una, me añade todos los productos a las 2 facturas y no consigo encontrar el error.

```
function Factura(numero, fecha) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    Factura.prototype = {
        nombreEmpresa: 'Casa Programadores, SL',
        direccionEmpresa: 'IES my House, 69',
        telefonoEmpresa: '612345678',
        nifEmpresa: 'H-78922492',
        nombreCliente: '',
        direccionCliente: '',
        telefonoCliente: '',
        nifCliente: '',
        productos: [],
        total: '',
        descuento: '',
        base: '',
        iva: '',
        formaPago: '',

        establecerCliente: function (nombreCliente) {
            this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        },

        establecerProductos: function (descripcion, cantidad, precio, parcial) {
            producto = {
                descripcion: descripcion,
                cantidad: cantidad,
                precio: precio,
                parcial: parcial
            }
            this.productos.push(producto);
        }
```

Instancio las facturas:

```
    let factura1 = new Factura(1, "01-02-2000");
    let factura2 = new Factura(2, "01-06-2021");
```

Añado los productos:

```
   factura1.establecerProductos("Producto 1", 10, 100, 1000);      
   factura1.establecerProductos("Producto 2", 20, 200, 4000);
   factura2.establecerProductos("Producto 1", 100, 1000, 10000);
   factura2.establecerProductos("Producto 2", 200, 2000, 40000);
```

El resto de métodos que tengo en prototype funcionan perfectamente.

Adjunto console.log de la factura1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Actualmente existen nuevas formas de [declarar clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Todos las propiedades que NO son del [tipo primitivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#estructuras_y_tipos_de_datos) y que su contenido/acción será distinto en cada instancia**, deben se declaradas como propiedades/métodos en el constructor y NO en el prototipo.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function Factura(numero, fecha) {
  this.numero = numero;
  this.fecha = fecha;
  this.productos = []; // ACA declaramos el arreglo de productos
}

Factura.prototype = {
  nombreEmpresa: 'Casa Programadores, SL',
  direccionEmpresa: 'IES my House, 69',
  telefonoEmpresa: '612345678',
  nifEmpresa: 'H-78922492',
  nombreCliente: '',
  direccionCliente: '',
  telefonoCliente: '',
  nifCliente: '',
  total: '',
  descuento: '',
  base: '',
  iva: '',
  formaPago: '',

  establecerCliente: function(nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
  },

  establecerProductos: function(descripcion, cantidad, precio, parcial) {
    let producto = {
      descripcion: descripcion,
      cantidad: cantidad,
      precio: precio,
      parcial: parcial
    }
    this.productos.push(producto);
  }
}

let factura1 = new Factura(1, "01-02-2000");
let factura2 = new Factura(2, "01-06-2021");


factura1.establecerProductos("Producto 1", 10, 100, 1000);
factura1.establecerProductos("Producto 2", 20, 200, 4000);
factura2.establecerProductos("Producto 3", 100, 1000, 10000);
factura2.establecerProductos("Producto 4", 200, 2000, 40000);

console.log('Factura 1:', JSON.stringify(factura1.productos));
console.log('Factura 2:', JSON.stringify(factura2.productos));
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto pasa porque en JavaScript el prototipo de un objeto en si mismo solo es un objeto valga la redundancia, que es compartido entre todas las instancias de la clase.

Debes utilizar siempre el constructor para declarar propiedades que son propias de la instancia y no declarar estas props en el prototipo.

Ahora, en lugar de utilizar prototipos puedes utilizar clases que están disponibles en JavaScript desde ESC2015 y estas son solo una mejora en la sintaxis de la herencia de los prototipos de JavaScript.

Y como ya te explicaron como utilizar el constructor en un objeto, te dejo un ejemplo de como utilizar las clases de JS:

```js
class Factura { 
  constructor(numero, fecha) {
    this.nombreEmpresa = 'Casa Programadores, SL';
    this.direccionEmpresa = 'IES my House, 69';
    this.telefonoEmpresa = '612345678';
    this.nifEmpresa = 'H-78922492';
    this.nombreCliente = '';
    this.direccionCliente = '';
    this.telefonoCliente = '';
    this.nifCliente = '';
    this.total = '';
    this.descuento = '';
    this.base = '';
    this.iva = '';
    this.formaPago = '';
    this.numero = numero;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.productos = [];
  }
  
  establecerCliente(nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
  }
  
  establecerProductos(descripcion, cantidad, precio, parcial) {
    let producto = {
      descripcion: descripcion,
      cantidad: cantidad,
      precio: precio,
      parcial: parcial
    }
    this.productos.push(producto);
  }
  
}

 let factura1 = new Factura()
 factura1.establecerProductos('hl',100,100,100)
 factura1.establecerProductos('hl',100,100,100)
 let factura2 = new Factura()
 factura2.establecerProductos('hl',100,100,100)
 factura2.establecerProductos('hl',100,100,100)
 
 console.log(factura1.productos)
```

Es tan simple como esto, a de mas puedes utilizar con JSNext propiedades privadas como en typescript, por ahora creo que solo es soportado por chrome. Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.